# Knockout CSS data binding does not work with Razor syntax

Tags: razor, knockout.js

Not sure why the following Razor syntax won't work:

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Description, new { @data_bind = "css: LabelCSS" })
```

If I use regular HTML syntax with attribute to bind to knockout, it works:

```
<span data-bind="attr: { 'class': LabelCSS }">Description</span>
```

My knockout ViewModel:

```
function ViewModel(dataFromServer) {

        var self = this;
        self.EnableDesc = ko.observable(dataFromServer.EnableDesc);

        self.LabelCSS = ko.computed(function () {
            return self.EnableDesc() ? "control-label" : "control-label-gray";
        }, self);
}
```

Comment: Shouldnt it then be `@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Description, new { @data_bind = "attr: { 'class': LabelCSS }" })` ?

Comment: Already tried that & does not work that way either.

Comment: What does your final HTML look like? You're using classes on span and label in your examples - does your css include tags in selectors?

Comment: You solution actually did work mxmissile. Not sure if I was looking at browser's cache behaviour first time around. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you answer your own question then and accept it? That way it won't be left open and people like me won't try to answer it. Also, you can omit the `@`-sign from `@data_bind`. data_bind is not reserved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to mxmissile for answering my question:

The syntax to be used is:

@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Description, new { data_bind = "attr: { 'class': LabelCSS }" })